# What are the properties around Pi products

Tags: summation, products

There are some well-known evaluations around summations like $\sum 1$ or $\sum i^2$ but what are these properties for products, specifically something like $\prod_{i=0}^{n-1} (n-i)$.

I basically have an algorithm with a terrible running time of $n \cdot (n-1) \cdot (n-2) \cdots (1)$ and I'd like to be able to express this in bigOh notation but I'm not sure what class it evaluates to. It is sort of $\mathcal{O}(n^n)$ but not really since each subsequent multiplication is $n-1$.

Comment: $n\cdot (n-1)\dots 2\cdot 1$ is called $n!$ (Factorial) Whas this the question?

Comment: haahaa! I was thinking too hard. You are right - so obvious.

Comment: Typesetting tip: \prod_{i=0}^{n-1} versus \prod_{i=0}^{n-1} in a "displayed" as opposed to "inline" setting look like this: $\displaystyle\prod_{i=0}^{n-1}$ versus $\displaystyle\Pi_{i=0}^{n-1}$.  In an "inline" setting, they look like this: $\prod_{i=0}^{n-1}$ versus $\Pi_{i=0}^{n-1}$.  These differences are why \prod is used instead of \Pi, and similarly \sum instead of \Sigma. ${}\qquad{}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The product you have is $\prod_{i=0}^{n-1} (n-i) = \prod_{i=1}^{n} i = n!$ ($n$ factorial).  These are well-known and you can compute them once (or even look them up).

Comment: Yep - I was thinking too hard and missed the obvious!

Answer (score 1):

The well-known [Stirling's formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation) says that $$n! \sim \sqrt{2\pi n} \left( \frac{n}{e} \right)^n$$ as $n\to\infty$.